# How can I find recent lines in commits that introduced a change?

Tags: git, git-log

How can I find in git the lines of code that added a specific method call or import recently?
If I  do `git log -Sfoo` or `git log -S"import some.class"` I get a list of commits and if I add `-p` I see the full commits but how can I see only the lines of the commits that introduced the change and not the whole commit?

Comment: What do you mean by "lines of the commits"? If you're looking for just the commit hash, you can add a `--oneline` to your `git log` and get it.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim:I want the lines of the commit that added the code. Not all the changes the commit introduced

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow. Can you post a contrived example that shows what you're getting and what you want? The `-U` flag will allow you to restrict the context around the diff therebey not showing you anything except what was changed.

Comment: I get the feeling that you're trying to do something for scripting though. Perhaps some explanation may yield a better solution.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim:`git log -Sfoo` gives me: SHA1, Author,Date ,Description. I want to get the lines of code relevant only

Comment: Try adding `--pretty="%b"` to your command.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: Honestly doing `git log --pretty="%b" -Sfoo" I have no idea what the output that I see is...

Comment: You're getting only the patch parts of all the commits that the log outputs. As I said earlier, if you edit your question to include an example of what you're seeing vs. what you want, it might be better.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim:git log -Sfoo gives me: SHA1, Author,Date ,Description

Answer (score 1):

```
git show | grep "import some.class"
```

Git show displays the changes in a commit (by default against HEAD, and a sha1 can additionally be provided), you can use this command in combination with `grep` to filter whatever changes you are looking for.

On the other hand, `git log -p` does pretty much the same thing as `git show`, except that it applies it to all commits in the current branch. So `grep` can also be applied to this command as well, and additionally specify how many lines to include around the matched string:

```
git log -p | grep "import" -5
```

Comment: This does not return anything

Comment: ```git show``` gives you information about the changes that have been made in a commit, and with ```grep``` you can filter what exactly you want to see. BTW grep is a unix command, so if you are on a windows machine, you might get an error instead....

Comment: I am on linux and when I pipe to grep I get nothing

Comment: @Avalanche It is quite likely that `HEAD` (which is the implied default commit for `git show` to operate on if you don't give it a specific argument) is not the commit the OP is interested in - would suggest `git show <commit> | ...`, with a little extra explanation as to how the OP might find the commit they want to look at (they're already part way there with `git log -S...`).

Comment: @twalberg Yeah, and it shows only one commit, while the OP wants to find all commits. ```git log -p``` does exactly the same thing as ```git show``` but  for all commits in the repository. The answer to this question is to simply use ```git log -p``` in combination with ```grep``` to track down any desired lines.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it difficult for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Thank you very much for your kind suggestion. I have taken my point and have edited the post according to your notice.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can use some features of [git-log](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) and [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) to achieve what you want.

`git log -p` Will show all commits and their corresponding chunks (useful when looking for particular code)

`git log --since "1 month ago"` The --since option is useful if you know that the code has been introduced recently

`git log origin/release/3.0.0 --not origin/release/2.10.4` The --not option will show you all commits that are in a one branch that are not in another.  This only works if you don't traditionally do rebasing as rebasing changes the sha1 of the commit.

`git log --author Steve` You can filter the search by the author of the commit.  Useful if you know that Steve is the one who made the change.

`grep -i` Does a case insensitive search

`grep -C` Will add the provided number of lines of context around a grep match.  Useful if you're trying to figure out the sha1 of the commit in which the change occured

Tying them together you should be able to use some of the options to identify the code change you're looking for like so:

`git log -p --since "1 month ago" | grep 'import some.class'`

`git log -p --since "1 month ago" | grep -i -C 50 'import some.class'`

`git log -p --since "1 month ago" --author Steve | grep -i -C 50 'import some.class'`

`git log -p origin/release/3.0.0 --not origin/release/2.10.4 | grep 'import some.class'`

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in `git log` to show changes to a specific function, so you could use that to help identify where a function was added to a specific file `git log -L:main:file --reverse` where main is the name of your function and file is your file name. The --reverse option will list from oldest to newest, so if a function was added, the first entry in the resultant log will be where it was added and then it will show changes to that as you go down. I tried this with a C++ style function declaration and it seemed to find it, ie `void foo::main()`, so it looks like it might work for Java as well? (but haven't verified that syntax). There is another option `git log -Sfunction_name` and you can replace function_name with any string and it will search for references to that string in the changes for each commit.

Answer (score 0):

`git blame -L <start>,<end> -- <file>` where `<start>` and `<end>` are line numbers, will show you what commit last touched that line. It is often handy to dig further back, and while you can do this with cmdline `git blame` I find that it is often easier to use `git gui blame`, e.g. `git gui blame -- foo.txt`. It will give you a simple GUI in which you can see what commit changed a line and even right click -> "blame parent commit" to search further back in history.